# django cmsplugin-blog not working

Tags: django, django-cms

I've installed Django 1.3 with django-cms. All is working correctly.
After that I installed cmsplugin-blog (from the extensions page of the djanog-cms website), version 1.1.1

I can't seem to get my urls working correctly. It looks like the correct urls are being produced by the blog app, but when opening the posts, I get 404 error. I think it might be a mistake in the urls.py of the blog application:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic.date_based import archive_year, archive_month, archive_day, object_detail
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list

from tagging.views import tagged_object_list

from menus.utils import set_language_changer

from cms.models import Title
from cms.utils.urlutils import urljoin

from cmsplugin_blog.feeds import EntriesFeed, TaggedEntriesFeed, AuthorEntriesFeed
from cmsplugin_blog.models import Entry
from cmsplugin_blog.views import EntryDateDetailView, EntryArchiveIndexView

blog_info_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
    'allow_empty': True,
    'paginate_by': 15,
}

blog_info_tagged_dict = {
    'queryset_or_model': Entry.objects.all(),
    'allow_empty': True,
}

blog_info_author_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.objects.all(),
    'allow_empty': True,
    'template_name': 'cmsplugin_blog/entry_author_list.html',
}

blog_info_month_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
    'month_format': '%m',
    'allow_empty': True,
}

blog_info_year_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
    'make_object_list': True,
    'allow_empty': True,
}

blog_info_detail_dict = dict(blog_info_month_dict, slug_field='entrytitle__slug')

def language_changer(lang):
    request = language_changer.request
    return request.get_full_path()

blog_archive_index = EntryArchiveIndexView.as_view()

def blog_archive_year(request, **kwargs):
    kwargs['queryset'] = kwargs['queryset'].published()
    set_language_changer(request, language_changer)
    return archive_year(request, **kwargs)

def blog_archive_month(request, **kwargs):
    kwargs['queryset'] = kwargs['queryset'].published()
    set_language_changer(request, language_changer)
    return archive_month(request, **kwargs)

def blog_archive_day(request, **kwargs):
    kwargs['queryset'] = kwargs['queryset'].published()
    set_language_changer(request, language_changer)
    return archive_day(request, **kwargs)

blog_detail = EntryDateDetailView.as_view()

def blog_archive_tagged(request, **kwargs):
    kwargs['queryset_or_model'] = kwargs['queryset_or_model'].published()
    set_language_changer(request, language_changer)
    return tagged_object_list(request, **kwargs)

def blog_archive_author(request, **kwargs):
    author = kwargs.pop('author')
    kwargs['queryset'] = kwargs['queryset'].published().filter(entrytitle__author__username=author)
    kwargs['extra_context'] = {
        'author': author,
    }
    set_language_changer(request, language_changer)
    return object_list(request, **kwargs)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', blog_archive_index, blog_info_dict, 'blog_archive_index'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 
        blog_archive_year, blog_info_year_dict, 'blog_archive_year'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/$', 
        blog_archive_month, blog_info_month_dict, 'blog_archive_month'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$', 
        blog_archive_day, blog_info_month_dict, 'blog_archive_day'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 
        blog_detail, blog_info_detail_dict, 'blog_detail'),
    (r'^tagged/(?P<tag>[^/]*)/$', blog_archive_tagged, blog_info_tagged_dict, 'blog_archive_tagged'),
    (r'^author/(?P<author>[^/]*)/$', blog_archive_author, blog_info_author_dict, 'blog_archive_author'),
    (r'^rss/any/tagged/(?P<tag>[^/]*)/$', TaggedEntriesFeed(), {'any_language': True}, 'blog_rss_any_tagged'),
    (r'^rss/tagged/(?P<tag>[^/]*)/$', TaggedEntriesFeed(), {}, 'blog_rss_tagged'),
    (r'^rss/any/author/(?P<author>[^/]*)/$', AuthorEntriesFeed(), {'any_language': True}, 'blog_rss_any_author'),
    (r'^rss/author/(?P<author>[^/]*)/$', AuthorEntriesFeed(), {}, 'blog_rss_author'),
    (r'^rss/any/$', EntriesFeed(), {'any_language': True}, 'blog_rss_any'),
    (r'^rss/$', EntriesFeed(), {}, 'blog_rss')      
)
```

Any help is appreciated!
If you need more configurations, I can post them.
Thanks

settings.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

gettext = lambda s: s

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))



DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG


MANAGERS = ADMINS

DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 0

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '*******',
        'NAME': '*******',
        'USER': '*******',
        'PASSWORD': '*********',
        'HOST': '*******',
        'PORT': '*******',
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl'
SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '**************************'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',

    'cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware', 
    'cmsplugin_blog.middleware.MultilingualBlogEntriesMiddleware',

    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)    

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'cms.context_processors.media',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
)

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('base.html', 'Main Template'),
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
)

#for cms-blog
JQUERY_JS = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js'
JQUERY_UI_JS = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js'
JQUERY_UI_CSS = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'debug_toolbar',

    'cms',
    'menus',
    'mptt',
    'south',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.file',
    'cms.plugins.snippet',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    'sekizai',

    'cmsplugin_contact',

    'cmsplugin_blog',
    'djangocms_utils',
    'simple_translation',
    'tagging',
    'staticfiles',
)
```

cms_app.py:

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class BlogApphook(CMSApp):
    name = _("Blog Apphook")
    urls = ["cmsplugin_blog.urls"]

apphook_pool.register(BlogApphook)
```

Comment: the website is at: http://shoestore.aspeqt.nl

Comment: the urls.py where you include the blog urls would be helpful

Comment: in my main site folder, I have this urls.py:
`   from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
    from django.contrib import admin
    admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^', include('cms.urls'))
 
    )`

Comment: Can you pastebin it? Where is the '/nl' prefix coming from? edit: nice, looks like it's working now!

Comment: Have you attached the [blog to a page](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-cms/en/latest/extending_cms/extending_examples.html#my-first-app-apphook)?

Comment: No, still not working, that was a php testpage, sorry for that :(

Comment: the blog is attached through the appHook of django-cms

Comment: and the /nl prefix is because of the multilingual middleware. If i remove these from config, then the nl prefix disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I've found the solution(s)....
After many hours of debugging I found out it was my mistake after all. I am using wsgi and the settings in the apache.wsgi file were incorrect.
In my sys.path I also appended a path from another django project. Since this append was the first one, it was never possible for any of my apps to read the correct settings files and url.py files.

After that it took me some time searching why the zinnia app (I moved from cmsplugin-blog to zinnia, which has much more options) wasn't working. This post helped in the right direction:
http://groups.google.com/group/django-blog-zinnia/browse_thread/thread/4de2827343fb79e0

After I put my url patterns in the correct order, everything worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the Apphook of the blog app to a page (see http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-cms/en/latest/extending_cms/extending_examples.html#my-first-app-apphook).

You need to do this for every language.

After you do that, you unfortunately have to restart the server.

Comment: The app is already hooked in cms_app.py. This app is a standard extention to the django-cms application. My cms_app.py looks like the code inserted in the post

Comment: the cms_app.py is just the definition of the application, not the actual hook itself. the hook itself is in the 'advanced settings' section in the page admin

Comment: I'm one step further now. After giving up on the cmsplugin-blog app, I tried installing Zinnia, which is a different blog app. It seems I keep getting the same error now: no reverse match. This happened with 3 different apps, but I'm very confused as to what this error means :(